# Pivoting a table in Pyspark based on a row_number

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot

Hello I need to pivot this table based on the row number.

```
+-----+-----+----------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------+
|index|Class|   PBUP_AC|item_code|Running_Index|row_number|exploded_score|
+-----+-----+----------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------+
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         1|            53|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         1|            54|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         1|            49|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         1|            46|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         1|            60|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         2|            54|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         2|            49|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         2|            46|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         2|            60|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         2|            55|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         3|            49|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         3|            46|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         3|            60|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         3|            55|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         3|            52|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         4|            46|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         4|            60|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         4|            55|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         4|            52|
|    1|    1|0000031503|    PFANA|            1|         4|            56|
```

I would like to get for each row number a separate column of each exploded_score. For example for row_number = 1, I should have 5 columns created for each integer of the corresponding exploded_score.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
pivoted_scores = exploded_df_1.groupBy("row_number").pivot("exploded_score").agg(first("exploded_score"))
```

The result I got was :

```
row_number:integer
1:integer
2:integer
5:integer
12:integer
14:integer
15:integer
20:integer
22:integer
23:integer
24:integer
25:integer
26:integer
27:integer
28:integer
29:integer
30:integer
31:integer
32:integer
33:integer
34:integer
35:integer
.......
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line

```
pivoted_scores = exploded_df_1.groupBy("row_number").pivot("exploded_score").agg(first("exploded_score"))
```

to this

```
pivoted_scores = exploded_df_1.groupBy("row_number").agg(collect_list("exploded_score"))
```

This will flatten `exploded_score` values into a list upon the group by.

Then, upon getting the lists, you can use the following statement to get each value in a different column.

```
pivoted_scores.select('row_number', 'exploded_score.*').show()
```